# How '\a' equal to '\7' in python?

Tags: python

```
a = '\a'
>>> b = '\7'
>>> a == b
True
>>>
```

How can `a` and `b` be equal? Can someone give the reason?

Comment: How did you discover this, without also immediately knowing why? It's a very strange thing to just try for no reason...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\a` is escaped character sequence for control character BEL (a for alert). The character's ASCII code is also happened to be 7, which matches the **octal** value in the escape sequence `\7`.

References:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character

http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Answer (score 3):

They're equal because `\a` means the ASCII Bell character in Python. Looking at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), the value of that character is 7.

Answer (score 2):

```
ord('\a')
7

ord('\7')
7
```

hence the two are equal.

This [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) will show that `\a` (BEL) has *octal* character code 7

Similarly, but perhaps now not so surprising,

```
a = ('\t')
b = ('\11')  # octal character code for tab

a == b
True
```

if you consult the ASCII table.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out `\a` and `\7` have the same value:

```
>>> a = '\a'
>>> b = '\7'
>>> a
'\x07'
>>> b
'\x07'
```

`\a` is the ASCII [Bell (BEL) character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) ([source](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html)) which indeed has value 7 in the ASCII table ([ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)).