# Pervent Ansible from changing \a to \u0007 in a variable

Tags: ansible

I have this user name `DOMAIN\adm123456789` as a `--extra-vars` called `SPSiteOwnerAlias` to my playbook:

```yaml
- name: Display username
  debug:
    msg: '{{ SPSiteOwnerAlias }}'
```

When I execute the playbook it displays:

```
"msg": "DOMAIN\u0007dm123456789"
```

I seems for some reason Ansible is changing `\a` to `\u0007`.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Try to set `DOMAIN\\adm123456789` (with a double-backslash)

Comment: Thank you unfortunately I have no control over input. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Might be related: [this issue on their tracker](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37712#issuecomment-375538160) and [this article of the doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/windows_usage.html#path-formatting-for-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in [one of the comment](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/4004#issuecomment-230623783) in the issue tracker of Ansible, using the `key=value` syntax could lead you to such issues. Of course, you won't be able to use YAML syntax, as advised in the comment there, because you are using the command line `--extra-vars` arguments, but even there, there are two possible sytaxes:

1. `key=value`, as you are using it, most probably
2. `{'key':'value'}`, with a [JSON string format](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line)

And if you happen to use the later, then your issue is no more!

Given the playbook *play.yml*

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ SPSiteOwnerAlias }}"
```

Here is a recap reproducing your issue:

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml --extra-vars "SPSiteOwnerAlias=DOMAIN\adm123456789"

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "DOMAIN\u0007dm123456789"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And here is a recap, using the JSON format:

```
--extra-vars "{'SPSiteOwnerAlias':'DOMAIN\adm123456789'}"
```

This one works properly:

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml --extra-vars "{'SPSiteOwnerAlias':'DOMAIN\adm123456789'}"

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "DOMAIN\\adm123456789"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Using json format has fixed my issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that `\a` has a special meaning in python.
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961081/how-a-equal-to-7-in-python).

You need to escape the `\` by using `\\` instead.

If you do not set the variable yourself (e.g. in the inventory), you can use a replace filter when using the variable:
`'{{ SPSiteOwnerAlias | replace("\a", "\\a") }}'`

Comment: Thanks very much but this substitution doesn't fix it. It gives the same result "DOMAIN\u0007dm123456789", I'll look more into it, it may be the right way to solve this.

Comment: It doesn't. I'll try other ways as we might need to escape those backslashes.

Comment: you are right, maybe `"\\u0007"` will do the trick. `"\a"` works in plain jinja2, maybe ansible is meddling there